# Use a KNN-regression algorithm in R

Tags: r, knn, weighted-average

I am working on using the k nearest neighbours with a certain variable identified(test) for determining the value of this same variable of an individual with this value non-identified(test). Two possible approaches can be done then:
first(easy one), calculate the mean value of the variable of the k individuals; second(best one), calculate a weighted distance value according to the proximity of the individuals.

My first approach has been using the **knn.index** function in **FNN** package for identifying the nearest neighbours, and then using the indexes, look for the values in the dataset to do the mean. This was working so slow, as the dataset is quite big. Is there any algorithm already implemented to do this calculation faster, and would it be possible to add weights according to distance?

Comment: Which was slow? Calling knn.index, or calculating the mean?

Comment: Calculating the mean value, because it has to access the dataset every time to locate each of the neighbours.

Comment: You wrote you have two approaches: "easy one" and "best one". Which of them was slow?

Comment: I tried the slow one, just a simple mean.

Answer (score 1):

After a week of trying to solve the problem, I found a function in R which was solving my question, this might help others who have strugled with the same issue.

The function is named **kknn**, and it is in the package **KKNN**. It lets you do a KNN regression, but weigthing the points by the distance.

Comment: A formula for KNN?  Seems odd.  Might be worth giving [KNeighborsRegresson](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neighbors.KNeighborsRegressor.html#sklearn.neighbors.KNeighborsRegressor) from sklearn in Python a shot.